# What would be the actual, real process for removing a wrongly-elected US President, if it ever really happened?

Tags: united-states, president, presidential-election

Let us be clear that for the purposes of this question the 46th President of the US was validly elected.

But let us imagine a situation in the future where it turns out that the US President was not validly elected - perhaps there really was massive fraud (not just fake fraud), or the President turns out not to be a US citizen. Let us also imagine that this comes out only after inauguration day, and that there is clear public support for removing the President, meaning that the states actually want to change the result.

**Could the President be removed, and if so how?**

Some ideas people might want to work with:

- Could state legislators vote to reverse their choice of electors, or to re-run the electoral college vote? Could Federal legislators vote to reverse their certification of the results and/or rerun the electoral college? Could they arbitrarily appoint a new President?
- Or would the President have to be impeached, on the assumption that they must have done something impeachable in order to get invalidly elected?

Comment: Have you reviewed what the constitution says about the presidential election process? It talks about the states choosing electors and congress confirming the electors votes. Nowhere does it mention the people voting and it also doesn't mention that the electors have to follow the votes of the people. Until the constitution is changed to actually consider how the people vote who ever the states chose for electors will be valid.

Comment: Yes. That's why I ask about the states changing their electors choices.

Comment: There is nothing in the constitution to allow for the states to change their choices. Once they are made the electors will vote, once the electors vote congress certifies the election, once that is done there is nothing that can be changed. If congress doesn't certify the election than they chose between the top 3 candidates in the electoral college voting and they can chose the one who got the least amount of votes and end up with a president and vice president from different parties.

Comment: Then please feel free to write an answer saying that, which is the information I was looking for.

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate of that question as my answer would just be a copy and paste of that for the most part.

Comment: Another related question: [If an impostor President was elected, and later found out, would the impersonated person then hold office?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/26868/19301)